# Android using async task while setting wallpaper

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have an app in which the user can set the image view in any fragment as wallpaper using an action bar item. I am using the following code for this:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch(item.getItemId())
        {
        case R.id.action_wall:
        {
            WallpaperManager wm=WallpaperManager.getInstance(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
              try{
                  wm.setBitmap(bmg1);
                  Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext(), "Wallpaper set successfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              }
              catch(IOException e)
              {
                  Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext(), "Wallpaper not set successfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              }
        }
        }

        return false;   


    }
```

The problem I am facing is that when user clicks on the menu item, the app hangs for a few seconds before showing the toast and setting wallpaper. I am aware that we can use async task to solve this though i am not sure how exactly it can be used here. Please help me out regarding this. Thanks

EDIT:
Here is my async task code:

```
class ImageTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{

    Context c;
    ProgressDialog pd;

    public ImageTask(Context ctx)
    {
        this.c=ctx;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() 
    {
        pd=ProgressDialog.show(c, "Please Wait", "Setting Wallpaper...");
    }
    public void onPostExecute()
    {
        pd.dismiss();
        Toast.makeText(c, "Wallpaer set successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        WallpaperManager wm1=WallpaperManager.getInstance(c);
        try {
            wm1.setBitmap(ImageFrag1.bmg1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: Whats the average size of your bitmap?

Comment: @IronBlossom  any idea how i can about it?

Answer (score 1):

As I understood, setting the bitmap image takes much time which forces the application to hang in. Better do this operation in any parallel thread instead of ui thread.
You need to initialize an AsyncTask and need to call execute() method inside switch statement.
You need to execute the line inside doInBackground method of AsyncTask.
For Example, try this..

```
private addImageTask mAddBitMap;

mAddBitMap.execute();

private class addImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        addBitMap();
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {

        try {
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception", e);
        }
    }
}
private void addBitMap(){
 WallpaperManager wm=WallpaperManager.getInstance(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
          try{
              wm.setBitmap(bmg1);
              Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext(), "Wallpaper set successfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }
          catch(IOException e)
          {
              Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext(), "Wallpaper not set successfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }
}
```

Comment: does this all come inside the onoptionsitemselected() method? or do i make it as a seperate class?

Comment: I think, You must call mAddBitMap.execute(); from onoptionsitemselected() method. If still It doesn't work, simply pass the arguments in the execute method, if needed.

Comment: im sorry i dont understand. I havent used this before. Could you clarify?

Comment: I will suggest you to go through the basics of AsyncTask implementation. You can check it here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html                                                                       http://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2012/03/17/understanding-asynctask-once-and-forever/

Comment: yes i have gone through these. But i found the examples that they have used, a bit difficult to understand. They are using using it to load internet url data, while my use is much simpler. Also, i noticed that this class will be a seperate one. So how can i the "bmg1" and the getactivity() methods etc in this?

Comment: check my update code. Now the progress dialog keeps on running and never closes. Where am i going wrong?